# Beautifulsoup grabs tag <p> between <h3> tag

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So, basically, I want to grab all text(`p` tag) in between `h3` tag **automatically** and **distinctly**.
How to write a code that can grab all text between `h3`?
For example, the following two lines:

**PARAGRAPH 1:**

```
<p>If you only have one small tumor in your lung and there is no evidence of cancer in lymph nodes or elsewhere, your doctors may recommend <a href="/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/surgery.html">surgery</a> to remove the tumor and the nearby lymph nodes.</p>
    <p>People who aren’t healthy enough for chemoradiation are usually treated with chemo by itself. This may be followed by radiation to the chest.</p>
```

**PARAGRAPH 2:**

```
<p>For most people with limited stage SCLC, surgery is not an option because the tumor is too large, it’s in a place that can’t be removed easily, or it has spread to nearby lymph nodes or other places in the lung. If you are in good health, the standard treatment is <a href="/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/chemotherapy.html">
```

In the text below. I want to write a code, not hardcore like specifying the line which includes `p` tag.

SO THAT IT CAN **AUTOMATICALLY** AND **DISTINCTLY** GRAB THE TEXT BETWEEN `h3` TEXT, OF COURSE, IT CAN BE CRAWL FOR OTHER PAGES NOT JUST THIS PAGE.

```
<h3>Stage I cancers</h3>
<p>If you only have one small tumor in your lung and there is no evidence of cancer in lymph nodes or elsewhere, your doctors may recommend <a href="/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/surgery.html">surgery</a> to remove the tumor and the nearby lymph nodes.</p>
<p>People who aren’t healthy enough for chemoradiation are usually treated with chemo by itself. This may be followed by radiation to the chest.</p>
<h3>Other limited stage cancers</h3>
<p>For most people with limited stage SCLC, surgery is not an option because the tumor is too large, it’s in a place that can’t be removed easily, or it has spread to nearby lymph nodes or other places in the lung. If you are in good health, the standard treatment is <a href="/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/chemotherapy.html">
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You just want the text between the <h3> tags?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish ye. You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [find_next_sibling()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<h3>Stage I cancers</h3>
<p>If you only have one small tumoremove</p>
<p>People who arent healthy enough.</p>
<h2>Skip this</h2>
<p>also Skip this</p>
<h3>Other limited stage cancers</h3>
<p>For most people with limited stage SCLC</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for section in soup.findAll('h3'):
    nextNode = section
    print "=================== %s ===================" % section.text
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.find_next_sibling()
        if nextNode and nextNode.name == 'p':
            print nextNode
        else:
            print "-------------------- h3 end --------------------\n"
            break
```

Comment: How did you know `find_next_sibling()` function?

Comment: @ewwink.. Learned another new cool ability that BeautifulSoup has today..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the text already in a variable then `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and run the code below. Otherwise, if you're trying to navigate to a website and scrape the page it's slightly different because you need to `import requests` add a variable for the `url = 'whatever website'` then a variable for the `page = 'requests.get(url)' and finally instead of the code below,`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml'). Keep the `find` variable and the for loop. This is all assuming that you're trying to grab only ALL the `<h3>` tags on the page.

```
html = """<h3>Stage I cancers</h3><p>If you only have one small tumor in your lung and there is no evidence of cancer in lymph nodes or elsewhere, your doctors may recommend <a href='/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/surgery.html'>surgery</a> to remove the tumor and the nearby lymph nodes.</p><p>People who aren’t healthy enough for chemoradiation are usually treated with chemo by itself. This may be followed by radiation to the chest.</p><h3>Other limited stage cancers</h3><p>For most people with limited stage SCLC, surgery is not an option because the tumor is too large, it’s in a place that can’t be removed easily, or it has spread to nearby lymph nodes or other places in the lung. If you are in good health, the standard treatment is <a href='/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/chemotherapy.html'>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
find = soup.findAll('h3')
for h3 in find:
    print(h3.text)
```

Comment: No. You misunderstand me. I want to crawl like the example above. I want to have two 2 distinct paragraphs like that.

Comment: What do you mean by two paragraphs? What tags are you wanting to have in paragraph 1 and paragraph 2?

Comment: I want all `<p>` tags in paragraph 1 between the first `<h3> </h3>` tag. Paragraph 2 all `<p>` tags between the second `<h3> </h3>` tag.

Comment: So you don’t want the h3 tags at all?

Comment: Send me the url so I can see the structure of the websites you have in mind.

Comment: this one https://www.cancer.org/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/by-stage.html

Comment: yes I dont want h3 tags. I just want p tags between them which seperates paragraphly

Answer (score 0):

```
html = """<h3>Stage I cancers</h3><p>If you only have one small tumor in your lung and there is no evidence of cancer in lymph nodes or elsewhere, your doctors may recommend <a href='/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/surgery.html'>surgery</a> to remove the tumor and the nearby lymph nodes.</p><p>People who aren’t healthy enough for chemoradiation are usually treated with chemo by itself. This may be followed by radiation to the chest.</p><h3>Other limited stage cancers</h3><p>For most people with limited stage SCLC, surgery is not an option because the tumor is too large, it’s in a place that can’t be removed easily, or it has spread to nearby lymph nodes or other places in the lung. If you are in good health, the standard treatment is <a href='/cancer/small-cell-lung-cancer/treating/chemotherapy.html'>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
find = soup.find_all('h3')
for h3 in find:
    print(h3.text)
```

Comment: Nice answer ‍

Comment: @Ashfaque No. You misunderstand me. I want to crawl like the example above. I want to have two 2 distinct paragraphs like that.

Comment: First you need to correct your question before asking for solution.
What you have mentioned above is get text between h3.
if you want to get text of <p> then just edit in find_all('p').

Comment: I want all <p> tags in paragraph 1 between the first <h3> </h3> tag. Paragraph 2 all <p> tags between the second <h3> </h3> tag.